# bootstrap Menu Dropdown is not showing on 14 inch screen with 100% zoom level while the same shows with 90% zoom level

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, z-index, dropdown, menubar

bootstrap Menu Dropdown is not showing on 14 inch screen with 100% zoom level while the same shows with 90% zoom level. (apart from 14 inch screen it shows well on other resolution screen like large screen and mobile devices.)

Comment: Welcome, this is your first question so don't worry about down votes it is just because the community likes things a certain way. Question should start with a problem description, followed by an explanation of what you've already tried to resolve it and conclude with your expectation. Try and give as much information as possible but keep the focus on one specific problem, this makes it easier to attract a knowledgeable person with your answer.

Comment: I got it fixed by removing the overflow:hidden property of page-wrapper.